# Enable scrollbar using highcharts.js

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to enable scrollbars using **highcharts.js**? All the answers tend to be leaning towards including **highstocks.js**, but this does not work for us and neither do we have the highstocks license.

The charts that I need are not supported by HighStocks. If this is not currently supported by HighCharts is there any future plan to add it?

Answer (score 2):

Scrollbar is available only in highstock.js, but in case when you use this library you can use highcharts. Take a look for simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/44aft/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {

    },
    navigator:{
        enabled:false
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled:true
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: [1,2,3,3,5,2]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still see the jsfiddle example is using HighStock.js, the chart types I need are not available in HighStock. I understand that you are creating a HighChart object but will this approach work for all chart types (say Box chart, Pareto chart etc ...) since these are not a part of HighStock.js. Also, we do not have license to use HighStock.js. Please let me know if my understanding is not correct.

Comment: It has a scrollbar but it doesn't scroll.

Comment: same question from my side also as user2317558 asked. Should this scroll bar work for all chart types?